# Confusion related to variance and mse

Tags: variance, rms

I was reading this wikipedia article and it states that MSE of a predictor is equivalent to variance of the error. To test it I did something like this

```
a = randn(10,1);
b=randn(10,1);

sqrt(mse(a,b))
std(a-b)
```

But the outputs are different, I get 1.3430 and 1.4292. I am not sure what's going on here. Any suggestions guys?

Comment: Is that Matlab code?

Answer (score 2):

There're a few points you'll want to investigate:

- You are interested in the "MSE of a predictor". Are you saying $a$ is an estimator of $b$ (or vice versa) - if so why? Given $a$ is an independently generated random variable?
- The MSE is a theoretical quantity, as it is an expected value. Calculations you do using random number generation are only ever going to be estimates of the MSE.
- Not clear what library the function mse is from.